# (iPhone) Picking UIImage, set an UIButton image with the image, but the image is bigger

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

Picking UIImage with the picker controller, set an UIButton image with the image, but the image is bigger then the button, instead of just fit the button.
Whats wrong?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the image as a background image to the button. not just image. its backgroundImage.

Answer (score 1):

Set the content mode of the imageview to something like UIViewContentModeCenter, or something similar that does not cause the image to scale.